# How to open console of particular machine from ESXi Shell?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an HP ProLiant DL180 G6 server with [VMware vSphere Hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESXi) (also called as ESXi).

I can use Windows vSphere Client and go to console of particular virtual machine:

[image]

But I need to work from Linux.

How to do same from ESXi SSH ? Something like `esxcli goconsole <vm_name_or_uri>` or `vim-cmd goconsole <vm_name_or_uri>`

I have

```
$ esxcli --version
Script 'esxcli' version: 6.7
```

P.S. I found [similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/360629/connecting-to-a-esxi-guest-remotely) question, but I'm not pleased with answer.

Comment: You can't, pleased or not. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t from the ESX shell, but if you need to use a Linux PC now you can use the VMRC from the web console. (https://my.vmware.com/fr/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMRC1006&productId=742)

The web interface is more agile than the traditional vsphere client.

Comment: That worked. I used console run and connected to esxi host as `vmrc -H <hostname> -U <login> -P <password>`

Comment: VMRC and web interface are different and valid options to get to a VM console from a Linux client